# Error connecting to server

Tags: html, ftp

I bought a hosting for free but i'm unable to connect it through the ftp client
it's showing that i'm unable to connect to the server because the party did not respond properly
i've entered all the details the ftp address the username and password still getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Try to raise connection timeout to 120s.

If no go, specify a port range for data ports. Free hosts may not be advisable if you're looking for 24/7 connections.

Comment: No I'm just a student trying to create a simple blog!